# Different privileges in kernel module execution

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-module, privileges

I have two places in a kernel module (Linux 3.13):

1. One is `module_init`
2. The other is code I hook with running an invalid opcode (by hacking interrupt description table).

My code is to enable hardware performance counter. When I put it in `module_init`, the code works fine. But when I put it to second place (triggered by running an instruction with an invalid opcode), the code gets a `permission denied` error (i.e. errno:`-13`).

Since both places are in a single kernel module, is it true that "even in kernel space, there are different privileges?"

Updates: something that is worth to mention is that when I run the invalid opcode as `root` in user space, the `-13` errno is gone; otherwise, it stays...

I speculate that "the privilege of an instruction execution decides that of its interrupt handler's execution."

Comment: You always have [OS privelleges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_level) on a processor. Even in *kernel mode*; not everything is allowed. Otherwise you could easily take over control.

Comment: @CommuSoft: Does this explain the difference between his kernel code in `module_init` vs. his kernel code for the opcode trap?

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would help a lot here, I think.

Comment: @CommuSoft are you saying that the handler code (case 2 in OP) are running in kernel but with privilege other than ring 0?

Comment: Some kernel functions intentionaly check priveleges of the current user. For more detailed answer, update your post with a function `enable hardware counter` and a way of `hacking interrupt description table`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `module_init` and your hook code running in different process. And there are different privileges between different process.

Generally, code must running in a process.

`module_init` always running in the period of insmoding module(See the sys_init_module function). When you insmod a kernel module, you must be a root. And the process is root too. So it running well.

But when you put the code in the IDT, it may running in a user process since a user process trigger a interrupt. So it got a -EPERM.

You can check the euid, uid, pid and comm in your code. Like this:

```
int hook_func()
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Code Called in hook_func. My pid: %d, comm: %s, uid: %d, euid: %d\n",
            current->tgid, current->comm, current->cred->uid, current->cred->euid);
    ...
}

int my_init()
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Code Called in my_init. My pid: %d, comm: %s, uid: %d, euid: %d\n",
            current->tgid, current->comm, current->cred->uid, current->cred->euid);
    ...
}

module_init(my_init);
```

Comment: is there a way to change such behavior (that the handler runs in the same privilege of the triggering process) by hacking IDT again?

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately, no.